# Back Button Redirect Script Issue

Tags: javascript, cordova

This script works, BUT NOT when having an iframe in page.

So why does the iframe breake this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Skip history-back and goes to index  
! function () {
var t;
try {
for (t = 0; 10 > t; ++t) history.pushState({}, "", "#");
onpopstate = function (t) {
t.state && location.replace("index.html")
}
} catch (o) {}
}();
</script>
```

Comment: First step, _I_ would do is to get rid of the empty catch statement that throws away all your valuable error messages.

Comment: Thanks Uwe for reply - Could you be more specific, I am rather new to js :-)